# VSCode gopls update issue

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

VsCode is warning me that gopls is outdated. When trying to update it I get this error

```
Installing golang.org/x/tools/gopls FAILED

1 tools failed to install.

gopls:
Error: Command failed: /usr/local/bin/go get -v golang.org/x/tools/gopls
go get: disabled by -mod=vendor
go get: disabled by -mod=vendor
```

It's actually happening with all gotools.

Any clue how to solve it?

Many thanks

Comment: Perhaps you have a flag like this set somewhere in your environment `GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor`?

Comment: Also, this for reference: https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/198438

Comment: @FilipWojciechowski thanks, removing that flag worked. I updated the dependencies and set it back.